# X.PagedList .NET Core First Page always selected in @Html.PagedListPager

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, pagedlist

I have created pagination for .Net Core 3 project using X.PagedList nuget, when I click on page number it call action that retrieve ***partial view*** and update div for data list, all ok but when I click on page number 2 the data in list updated but current page selection is still on 1, it should changed to 2. and every time click on page greater that 1 the selection remain on 1 in PagedListPager.

```
    @Html.PagedListPager(Model.OrderViewModels, page => Url.Action("OrdersSearch2", "Orders",
    new { ViewBag.SearchName, page = page }),
    PagedListRenderOptions.EnableUnobtrusiveAjaxReplacing(new PagedListRenderOptions
    {
        LiElementClasses = new string[] { "page-item" },
        PageClasses = new string[] { "page-link" },
                                                               
    }
    , new AjaxOptions()
    {
        HttpMethod = "POST",
        UpdateTargetId = "OrdersList",

    }))
```

OrdersIndexViewModel

```
    public class OrdersIndexViewModel
{
    public IPagedList<OrderViewModel> OrderViewModels { get; set; }
    public SearchOrderViewModel SearchOrderViewModel { get; set; }

}
```

And my Action in Orders controller

```
        public ActionResult OrdersSearch2(int? page)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View(mymodel);
        }
        OrderSearch ors = new OrderSearch();

        ors.PageNumber = page ?? 1;

        var entitiesList = orderService.FindBy(ors).ToPagedList(ors.PageNumber, 5);


        var model = new OrdersIndexViewModel();
        model.OrderViewModels = entitiesList.ToViewModels();
        return PartialView("_OrdersListPartial", model.OrderViewModels);

    }
```

Index.cshtml

```
        @model OrdersIndexViewModel
<div id="OrdersList">
           <partial name="_OrdersListPartial.cshtml" model="Model.OrderViewModels" />
</div>
```

[image]

_OrdersListPartial.cshtml

```
@model X.PagedList.IPagedList<OrderViewModel>
@{
    int rowNo = 0;
}


<div id="basic-examples">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-content">
            <div class="card-body">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12">
                    <input type="submit" value="New Order" class="btn btn-primary mr-1 mb-1 waves-effect waves-light" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("AddOrder", "Orders")'" />

                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="" id="OrdersList">
                @if (Model == null || Model.Count == 0)
                {
                    <div class="alert alert-warning">No Orders</div>
                }
                else
                {
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-12">
                            <div class="card">
                                <div class="card-header">
                                    <h4 class="mb-0">Orders List</h4>
                                </div>
                                <div class="card-content">
                                    <div class="table-responsive mt-1">
                                        <table class="table table-hover-animation mb-0">
                                            <thead>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <th>#</th>
                                                    <th>ID</th>
                                                    <th>CUSTOMER NAME</th>
                                                    <th>CREATED</th>
                                                    <th>DELIVERY DATE</th>
                                                    <th>STATUS</th>


                                                    <th>OPERATORS</th>
                                                    <th></th>
                                                    <th style="display:none"></th>
                                                </tr>
                                            </thead>
                                            <tbody>
                                                @foreach (var i in @Model)
                                                {
                                                    rowNo = rowNo + 1;
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td>@rowNo</td>
                                                        <td>@ViewBag.OrdersPrefix @i.ID</td>
                                                        <td><i class="fa fa-circle font-small-3 text-success mr-50"></i>@i.CustomerName</td>
                                                        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(x => i.CreatedDate)</td>
                                                        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(x => i.DeliveryDate)</td>
                                                        <td>@i.OrderStatusText</td>

                                                        <td class="p-1">
                                                            <ul class="list-unstyled users-list m-0  d-flex align-items-center">
                                                                <li data-toggle="tooltip" data-popup="tooltip-custom" data-placement="bottom" data-original-title="Vinnie Mostowy" class="avatar pull-up">
                                                                    <img class="media-object rounded-circle" src="../../../app-assets/images/portrait/small/avatar-s-5.jpg" alt="Avatar" height="30" width="30">
                                                                </li>
                                                                <li data-toggle="tooltip" data-popup="tooltip-custom" data-placement="bottom" data-original-title="Elicia Rieske" class="avatar pull-up">
                                                                    <img class="media-object rounded-circle" src="../../../app-assets/images/portrait/small/avatar-s-7.jpg" alt="Avatar" height="30" width="30">
                                                                </li>
                                                                <li data-toggle="tooltip" data-popup="tooltip-custom" data-placement="bottom" data-original-title="Julee Rossignol" class="avatar pull-up">
                                                                    <img class="media-object rounded-circle" src="../../../app-assets/images/portrait/small/avatar-s-10.jpg" alt="Avatar" height="30" width="30">
                                                                </li>
                                                                <li data-toggle="tooltip" data-popup="tooltip-custom" data-placement="bottom" data-original-title="Darcey Nooner" class="avatar pull-up">
                                                                    <img class="media-object rounded-circle" src="../../../app-assets/images/portrait/small/avatar-s-8.jpg" alt="Avatar" height="30" width="30">
                                                                </li>
                                                            </ul>
                                                        </td>

                                                        <td>
                                                            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "EditOrder", "Orders", routeValues: new { ID = i.ID })
                                                        </td>
                                                        <td style="display:none">
                                                            <i class="feather icon-trash"></i>
                                                            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "DeleteOrderDetailTempItem", "Orders", routeValues: new { ID = i.ID }, htmlAttributes: new
                                                                  {
                                                                      @data_ajax = "true",
                                                                      @data_ajax_method = "Get",
                                                                      @data_ajax_update = "#OrderDetailList",
                                                                      @data_ajax_failure = "onFailureDefault",
                                                                      @data_ajax_success = "ViewOnSuccess",
                                                                  })


                                                        </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                }
                                            </tbody>
                                        </table>
                                    </div>



                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                }

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi @Aziz, I think you need share more code then we could reproduce your issue.

Comment: I added extra code .Thanks Rena

Comment: Hi @Abdulaziz, still could not reproduce your issue. Also your provided code has something wrong, you could see that you pass `model="Model.OrderViewModels` to partial view, it does not match the partial view here:`@Html.PagedListPager(Model.OrderViewModels`. Please share the correct code sir. Besides, what is your onAjaxSuccess method?

Comment: I added now partial view code and OrdersIndexViewModel which passed to Index view code and in onAjaxSuccess just call alert and I remove it for confuse .Thanks Rena